# como eu faço pra não executar os próximos métodos?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

```
        `método onde chamo todos os meus outros metodos de verificação`
        public bool ValidarCamposDoForm()
        {
            ValidaNome();
            ValidaCpf();
            ValidaLogradouro();
            ValidaNumeroDaCasa();
         }
```

todos os métodos tem uma validação especifica pra cada textbox e uma mensagem de erro.

toda vez que deixo minhas textboxs em branco ele executa todos os meus métodos e exibi a mensagem de erro de todos os meus métodos no meu form, gostaria que caso desse erro em um método ele não executasse os próximos métodos ou pelo menos não mostrasse a menssagem de erro desses métodos.

como faço?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Depende de como você fez esses métodos de validação, se eles estão retornando false quando não é validado, basta retornar que ele não irá executar os outros.

```
var validar = ValidaNome();
if (validar == false) then
{
  return;
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: eu faço isso no meu método ValidarCamposDoForm ou onde eu faço a validação do nome?